# Where can I download Grails 2.1.4?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am looking to download an old version of Grails, specifically 2.1.4. I do not understand why Grails are keeping the old versions a secret.

Comment: There's no secrecy related to the old versions. Maybe they need some general content accessibility improvements but it's not difficult to find the download links either.

Comment: From the close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not *that* secret.

Go to [`http://grails.org/download`](http://grails.org/download) and choose "Download previous release".

Just choose major version 2.1 and download the version of your choice ([2.1.4](http://dist.springframework.org.s3.amazonaws.com/release/GRAILS/grails-2.1.4.zip))

Answer (score 0):

On the release notes page ... down on the page is the download link .... [check this for download 2.1.4 version](http://dist.springframework.org.s3.amazonaws.com/release/GRAILS/grails-2.1.4.zip)